# How to solve 488 error with mjsip codec mismatch?

Tags: codec, mjsip

I am using Mjsip to build a softphone. I have integrated multiple codecs with it. For test purpose when I make call to another client which is a Portsip 2.0 (G729, ULAW, ALAW, GSM, ILBC) I get an 488 error (Not accepted here). I have integrated G729, ULAW, ALAW, ILBC with my project and codec precedence is g729:ulaw:alaw:ilbc. But after compiling the project if i initiate a call from portsip to my phone. It rings. Then If I call back from my phone it doesn't show any error. It always show error if I tried to call from my softphone after compiling.